# SonarQube and Docker doesn't work anymore

Tags: docker, sonarqube

I'm using sonarqube with docker.

1. I launch the container sonarqube with: `[docker run -p 9000:9000 sonarqube][1]`
2. I make the settings in localhost:9000 in chrome
3. I launch a scanner like that: `docker run -e SONAR_HOST_URL="http://localhost:9000" -e SONAR_LOGIN="hereismytoken" -v "C:\Users\Flavien.Besseau\Documents\internProject\intern-project-front:/usr/src" sonarsource/sonar-scanner-cli`

Then I got this error: [The problem](https://ibb.co/zNc2GzR) and I don't understand why at all because it worked before.

Thanks in advance

Comment: That's the whole error; the words `The problem`?  Can you edit the question to include a [mcve] including enough of your application code to demonstrate the issue, and the actual complete error messages; in plain text and not images, directly in the question and not behind links?

Comment: `it worked before` <= before what ? What happened since it last worked? Did you upgrade the image(s)? Did you upgrade docker? Did you take a bath with your laptop? .... In any case, I don't see how `SONAR_HOST_URL="http://localhost:9000"` can work  to join the server from inside a docker container running your scanner. This is telling your scanner to connect to its own container on port 9000 where sonarqube is obviously not running. From your very first command, you can join it directly on the sonarqube container or on your docker controller trhough the mapped port.